# Is it possible to move the "AutoComplete.vb" file out of the App_Code folder and into a new namespace/project?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-2.0, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When setting up the Ajax Control Toolkit's AutoComplete control, it creates an `AutoComplete.asmx` and a `AutoComplete.vb` file.  The `AutoComplete.vb` file automatically ends up in the App_Code folder.  I was hoping to move all of these styled-classes into a separate namespace, but the compiler simply does not dig it.

Is this possible, or must it be within the presentation layer to access the "Web" related namespaces?

Errors when moving it and changing the reference to it include things like:

> Type 'WebService' is not defined.
>
> Typed 'WebServiceBinding' is not
> defined

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be in the App_Code folder. If you add a new web service, you can use the "ServicePath" property of the AutoCompleteExtender to specify the location of the webservice to use.

- Have you got a reference to System.Web (System.Web.Services) where you move it to?
- Have you tried creating a new web service and pointing the AutoCompleteExtender at it?

Comment: Autocomplete loses all of its webservices.  "Type 'WebService' is not defined.  Typed 'WebServiceBinding' is not defined, etc.